# Route with name 'XXX' does not exist vuerouter

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I am using `Laravel 8` `Vuejs 2.17` and `VueRouter 3.4`,
i have two components Orders.vue and Users.vue
this is how my app.js looks like

```
require("./bootstrap");
window.Vue = require("vue");

import Vue from "vue";

//? Vue router
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import routes from "./routes";
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes
});


new Vue({
    router,
}).$mount("#app");
```

and here is how router.js looks like

```
import Orders from './appComponents/Orders';
import Users from './appComponents/Users';

const routes = [
    {
        path: "/admin/orders",
        name: 'orders',
        component: Orders,
    },
    {
        path: "/admin/users",
        name: 'users',
        component: Users,
    },


];
export default routes;
```

i called the routes in my laravel view like :

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'users' }">users</router-link>
<router-link :to="{ name: 'orders' }">Orders</router-link>
```

the browser response with

```
 [vue-router] Route with name 'users' does not exist
 [vue-router] Route with name 'orders' does not exist
```

i also tried to call the routes by its path but still not working, anyone please can help me.

Comment: try `import routes from "./routes";` to `import { routes } from "./routes";`

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution, i've installed a an npm modules, and there was a conflict between the module app.js and my app.js